# PHP: Highlight every second row of table

Tags: php, css, arrays, loops, echo

I use this code to create a HTML table

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= $requiredRows; $x++) {       
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo someArrayStuff($x);
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $someArrayStuff[$x][arrayinfos];
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $someArrayStuff[$x][arrayinfos];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Now I want to highlight every second row with a background color, how can I do this with PHP? I don't want to define it in the CSS file.

---

Thanks for all your help, now it works with this code:

```
if($x%2 == 0) { echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFF'>"; } else { echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFF'>"; }
```

Comment: use `$x%2==0` logic and define inline css style

Comment: this can easily be done with jQuery if you want to go that route; it's an option.

Comment: I understand you have your reasons for not including styling in the CSS, but styling via markup is considered bad practice.

Comment: Question not of SO standard

Comment: Oh no! bgcolor is deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: you can use if($x % 2 == 0) but you really shouldn't do it like that.

Comment: sure, simply changing bgcolor='color' to style="background-color: color"

Answer (score 5):

```
if($x%2 == 0) {
    echo '<tr class="bg-highlight">';
} else {
    echo "<tr>";
}
```

and define a css class:

```
.bg-highlight {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to define a CSS class you can simply use: if($x%2 == 0) { echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFF'>"; } else { echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFFFF'>"; }

Comment: please note that the `bg-color`attribute is no longer valid in HTML5 http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use mod. $x%2 will check if its a even row. which will be alternate row. If its found as even row then a different background color is given.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= $requiredRows; $x++) {  
    if($x%2 == 0) { //even
    echo "<tr style="background-color: #FF0000">";
    } else { // odd
    echo "<tr>"; 
    }

    echo "<td>";
    echo someArrayStuff($x);
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $someArrayStuff[$x][arrayinfos];
    echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";
    echo $someArrayStuff[$x][arrayinfos];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a dynamic class which will alter as per your loop

```
$class = ($x%2 == 0) ? "highlight" : "";
echo "<tr class='$class'>";
```

Just create a class named

```
.highlight{
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or You can simply use this code in css for odd or even rows of table.

```
div:nth-child(even)
{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= $requiredRows; $x++) {       
    echo "<tr";
    if ($x % 2 === 1) {echo " style=\"background-color: yourFavoriteColor;\"";}
    echo ">";
              ..................
```